# C++ manage large buffer of images

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, buffer, mat

I have a C++ application that reads and processes a video stream. I have two threads: one thread to read the stream and a second thread for processing. I access the stream with OpenCV VideoCapture and put frames (`cv::Mat`) in the [readerwriterqueue](https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue) buffer. From another thread, I read the frames from the buffer and process them.

Sometimes processing may take a lot of time and processing thread start to fall behind (while frames are put into the queue at the same speed). This increases the buffer size and may eventually take all available memory and hang the whole system. I know that Windows uses pagefile if there is not enough RAM, but the system still becomes pretty laggy. I need to make sure this won't happen.

I thought about setting a limit on the buffer size and offload frames to disk when the buffer is full. Then read them back in the queue when there is space. Would that work? Are there any good alternatives? How would one handle such a problem? Is my current approach (image queue) valid? Please advice.

Comment: What happens if your processing thread never catches up?

Comment: Why not use multiple threads for processing?  Each frame should have a timestamp so it should be fairly simple to reconstruct the output stream in the correct order.

Comment: _I thought about setting a limit on the buffer size and offload frames to disk when the buffer is full._ Isn't that what swapping pages to page file already does? Another thought on this are memory-mapped files. However, at first hand I would try like recommended by @G.M.

Comment: @Richard Critten it is highly unlikely to happen, so it is less of a concern for now.

Comment: @G.M. great idea! I will try that.

Comment: Use a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of a fixed size.

Comment: @rustyx it may work. But if the buffer is full i will lose some frames and i need all of them.

Comment: If frames are generated faster than you can process them, you have a problem that can't be solved.  Eventually any scheme will run out of resources.  You must be able to consume the frames at least as fast as they are generated, or no algorithm will work.